# Временная зона пользователя в проекте CodeIgniter

Tags: дата, timezone, php, javascript, codeigniter

Здравствуйте! Пишу проект на CodeIgniter, с модулем авторизации DX_Auth.
Мне необходимо чтобы функция <?=date('d-m-Y H:i');?> выводила время которое в данный момент у пользователя. 
date.timezone = UTC.

Есть несколько вариантов:
При регистрации пользователя в поле timezone добавить его зону из javascript:

```
(new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60)*(-1); //Допустим = 3
```

Но в дальнейшем мне придётся постоянно загружать это значение из БД? Это лишние запросы. Хотя можно сохранить значение в cookie, и загружать его оттуда. Но тут вопрос, как мне использовать это значение, чтобы оно было как серверное?

```
<?=date_default_timezone_set($_COOKIE['timezone']);?>
```

И вопрос, где мне указать эту функцию, чтоб она работала во всем проекте CodeIgniter?
И что делать если человек поменяет своё местоположение?

Есть вариант, отправлять API запрос GeoIP, и получать оттуда временную зону по IP-адресу, но мне кажется это лишнее. Не очень хорошо, когда загрузка твоего проекта зависит от загрузки другого.

Какие ещё можете дать рекомендации и решения, относительно моей проблемы?

Comment: > Но тут вопрос, как мне использовать это значение, чтобы оно было как серверное?

Никак, оно не серверное, оно конкретного пользователя. В зависимости от типа хранения надо либо использовать DateTimeOffset, либо прибавлять/отнимать от timestamp количество часов.

> Есть вариант, отправлять API запрос GeoIP, и получать оттуда временную зону по IP-адресу, но мне кажется это лишнее. Не очень хорошо, когда загрузка твоего проекта зависит от загрузки другого.

Довольно странно сначала отказаться от быстрой БД, а затем рассматривать вопрос запроса полноценного сервиса при каждой загрузке.

Comment: Данный по геоайпи могут лежать и [прямо на сервере](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.geoip.php), только я все равно бы от них отказался, потому что люди могут банально сидеть через прокси. Пусть сохраняется временная зона при регистрации и подтягивает вместе с основными данными пользователя, а он указывает уж что ему удобно.

Comment: @Fike, Хорошо, так как мне получить лучше его локальное время, и потом записывать его в БД, и доставать оттуда? или в БД записывать лучше в UTC 00:00?

Comment: @chuikoff таймзону. Либо строковый код, либо смещение в часах/минутах/секундах, в зависимости от того, как будет использоваться.